# Is there a way to prevent ie7 from loading some inline javascript?

Tags: javascript

do you know of any way to prevent a script i have on a web page to be loaded by IE7 only?

The script works fine in all other browsers so I just wanted to disable it on IE7.

Is this at all possible?

Alex

Comment: Wouldn't it be smarter to make the script work in IE7 as well ? Show it to us and maybe we can help.

Comment: Does this mean that the script is working in IE6?

Comment: @DidierGhys you are right it's just that i wanted a quick n dirty solution fr the time being, and i would look into js later. i didnt write the js myself and it's difficult to pinpoint the issue

Comment: This is why you should never do quick&dirty... because you will simply never take care of the js later. I've worked on projects completely built upon quick&dirty solutions for this exact same reason. This is part if your job to make clients understand that resolving some bugs takes time and it is your responsability to keep a clean code base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 7') < 0){
//do your non-IE7 stuff here
}
```

or even better

```
function DoSomStuff(){
  if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE 7') > 0 ) return;
//do your non-IE7 stuff here
}
```

Comment: I think this is the one :) I will try it out!

Comment: Please don’t use this! http://stackoverflow.com/a/9229864/96656 is a much more robust solution.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this works for you:

```
<!––[if !IE 7]>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="different"></script>
    <![endif]––>
```

Comment: This will load the script if its IE7, whereas the OP is wanting to disable the script.  You are missing your `not` operator.

Comment: Even with your edit, the whole thing will be recognized as a HTML comment by non-IE browsers.

Comment: yeah but he only wants to target IE7 so its fine

Comment: @EvilP: no, he wants to target *not IE 7*, which means IE 6, 8, 9, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Opera, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is, using [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

```
<!--[if !(IE 7)]>
<script>
    // Your script here
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: This won't load the script in non-IE browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use down-level revealed [conditional comments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (with a bit of extra markup to satisfy validators):

```
<!--[if !(IE 7)]><!-->
    <script src="myscript.js"></script>
<!--<![endif]-->
```

However, any good web developer would recommend that you use feature detection instead of browser detection for your scripts.  It's also possible that your IE 7 problem could be easily solved, so perhaps you might want to post it as a separate question.